# Run shell from Python and make it active

Tags: python

I use Python scripts to prepare some stuff for long quantum calculations. So, when I run target binary from terminal

```
targetbin file.inp > file.out
```

I can see that process is still running. With Python I do some automations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# blah blah blah

cmd = ' '.join([targetbin, modified_inp_file, some_options, '>', created_out_file])
# /usr/bin/targetbin /tmp/XXX.inp -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 > file.out

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

run it from terminal:

```
pythonscript -x 1 -y 2 -z 3 file.inp
```

and it works fine, but it doesn't hold shell. After Python initiate the process I want to delegate it completely to the shell and then exit Python itself, as if I entered `cmd` myself. Is it possible?

Comment: Try `python -i`?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't hold shell"? Is `targetbin` somehow terminated when your script exits?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way -

1. Run a shell script that run the python script.
2. Python will do the automations and will run the the process run by POPEN.
3. Shell script will do `fg`. (Alternatively, you can get the `PID` from python and run `kill -CONT <pid>`).

Comment: A possible solution, thank you. I hope it is a more direct way without an additional layer